# Checking whether a linux machine is idle

Tags: linux, power-management

I'd like to shut down my machine if it is idle, and am looking for the most reliable definition of "idle". It should measure whether the computer (an end-user laptop or desktop machine) is performing useful work or not. Notably, here are some things I'd like to check for:

- No user activity

  `w` command prints idle time for terminal sessions

  [xprintidle](http://www.alex.ballas.org/tag/xprintidle/) seems to do the same for X, using the X screensaver extension
- Low load average

  `uptime` prints load average
- No running downloads

  [bwm-ng](http://www.gropp.org/?id=projects&sub=bwm-ng) computes current network and disk usage

Now my questions:

1. Are there any existing tools performing these checks?
2. What other activities should we check for to make this more reliable? Open network connections maybe? Or a whitelist of processes that should never be interrupted? Could we somehow learn what characterizes useful work, using some machine learning techniques?

Looking forward to your ideas and suggestions!

Comment: You might have forgotten user programs run thru `crontab` or `at`. They don't have controlling terminals. But why really are you asking???

Comment: The reason I asked is because yesterday night, I started a build job, then went to bed. It would have been nice if the machine could shut down at the end of the build. Yet, the build consists of several processes, has times when it compiles stuff and times when it waits for the network... So I thought I'd look for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way IMHO is this one in `Perl` in a `shell` :

```
cpan -i X11::IdleTime # or any otherway to install X11::IdleTime module
sleep 2
perl -MX11::IdleTime -e 'print GetIdleTime(), $/;'
```

Comment: This seems to do the same as xprintidle mentioned above... it's one piece of a much larger puzzle I'm asking for.

Comment: Is my command or xprintidle isn't sufficient in a crontab job ?

Comment: Well, no... as I wrote, the X11 idletime is just one out of many aspects. If I would shut down a machine only based on that information, I might interrupt an important download.

Comment: I got "Can't locate X11/IdleTime.pm in @INC" message.